# How to set text color of Gridview

Tags: android, gridview, colors

I can change background color, but how can I change
the text color of Gridview content?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944674/text-color-by-programmatically-created-grid-view-content

Comment: [Look at this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944674/text-color-by-programmatically-created-grid-view-content)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GridView is just a layout control.  You want to change the color of the component that you are putting inside of the GridView - probably a TextView.  Try TextView.setTextColor().

Comment: 10x. I'm using "ArrayAdapter<String> adapter" and now i'm changing his text color layout

Comment: Do the android:textColor="" inside your layout xml file for the adapter. Hope this will help