# Text color by programmatically created grid view content

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I understand how to do this in design view, but I'm not sure how to create a style based on programmatically created elements. I followed a tutorial and here's where I'm at:

I have a grid view which is populated by a string array as in the code below:

```
...
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strData);
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Each element of the string array populates the grid just fine.

How would I set the text color of the items added to the gridView?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2 solutions: *dynamically* or with a *custom layout*.

- **Dynamically**: you can set a text color by using `setTextColor(...)` when you Override the `getView()` method in your ArrayAdapter, something like this:

  ```
  gridview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strData) {
      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
          TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
          text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color));
          return view;
      }
  });
  ```
- **Custom Layout**: this is the simplest way, build a custom layout as:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/tv"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:textColor="@color/my_color"
      android:background="@drawable/my_background"
      android:padding="5sp"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:gravity="center" />
  ```

  Then, set it to your adapter:

  ```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_layout_above, strData);
  ```

Even if, you wanted this dynamically, I'm not sure but I think it's better to do with a custom layout.
Hope this helps.

Comment: `@drawable/rectgrad` and `@color/font_content` don't exist in my app, but by adding the custom layout i am seeing the background color change when i set it to a hex value. the textColor is not affecting the text, although i'm making the assumptin i can switch the value to hex `#ffffff`. Definitely closer!

Comment: This was an example.. You can change every value according to your needs. You can do this `android:textColor="#ffffff"`, this `android:textColor="#FFffffff` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16890937/2668136)) or this one `android:textColor="@color/my_color_white"` (according to [colors.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color)). You can find all the [color resources](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7323234/2668136) used in android.

Answer (score 0):

By creating a custom layout and supplying  it to your `ArrayAdapter`. Currently you are supplying the default layout `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`. Create a new layout xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/flFragmentContainer"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And style it however you want.

You can use it like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_layout, R.id.tvText, strData);
```